# CreateJS to native android app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, game-engine, haxe, createjs

As is well known, nothing would be as efficient as native code, so, for my situation, I have a js haxe project which based on createJS

How would I rewrite it to native android app? I thought that if I just find a 2D gaming engine for android that has AS3 APIs, that would make it easy to the transition .. but that is just an idea ..

Anyone knows a good 2D game engine that has AS3 apis on android?

Forget about phonegap, as it uses the native webview of android which dose not fully support HTML5 and not optimized enough ,,

Any guidance there?

Comment: you could take a look at cocoonjs (www.ludei.com) - they will package your html5-app and use a Direct3D Stage to display the contents - you do have an HTML5-output currently, right?

Comment: Yes, I have HTML5 out working nicely in most browsers, do you think they will get a high performance results like those I get in Chrome?

Comment: I've just sent them an email, lets see what they will say!

Comment: You can test it yourself in like 15minutes, just download the testing-app, ZIP your game and test it in the testing app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideateca.cocoonjslauncher&hl=en ;)